# Migration of ebtables arp rule to nftables

Tags: iptables, nftables

I'd like to move to nftables (Ubuntu trusty, kernel 3.19). However I wonder how to migrate ebtables rules for ARP packets:

> -p ARP --arp-op Request --arp-ip-src 192.168.178.237 --arp-mac-src 2:fb:c5:e0:ef:a3 -j ACCEPT

The command `nft add rule bridge filter qemu1-o arp operation request counter accept` works, however I can't figure out how to add the ip/mac contraints to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `nftables` have no implemented syntax for source and destination ipv4 address in arp tables right now.

Empirically I found out that the next expressions can be used instead:

- `plen 4 @nh,64,32` (source ip)
- `plen 4 @nh,96,32` (destination ip)

IPv4 address in value should be specified in decimal `integer` type.

You can use some online converter for get your IP-address to numeric format.

In your example `192.168.178.237` will be `3232281325`

So final rule will looks like:

```
nft add rule arp filter input arp operation request arp plen 4 @nh,64,32 3232281325 ether saddr 2:fb:c5:e0:ef:a3 counter accept
```

PS: You can use `xtables-nft-multi` from the last iptables package which provides `nf_tables` compat backend for import your old commands and check the new syntax.